# Bundling ReactJS and ExpressJS

Tags: reactjs, express, routes

Based on my understanding, if i wanna to run a web app with express and use react as its UI, i should run express server with app code and serve react with that through fetch. is it correct? I don't think so!

See, Request goes to express server,

then express should request from react to response with specific UI that attached requested data,
or
react serve the request and routes?

if the question is confusing, so sorry/

Comment: You're on the right track. The express server will provide the API that serves the UI files (like the HTML, CSS and Javascript) and also provides any functionality (like routes for searching databases or fetching resources). However Express doesn't "request things from React". React code gets converted into regular Javascript files during building. These files (along with HTML and CSS) are then consumedby the browser. However, the browser has to get them from somewhere, that's where the server comes in. Express lets you make a server to serve those files (as well as do other things).

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks, HTTP request goes to server express, but we have fetch in our react code ( react server running concurrent! ) so, how react know when do fetch and how express coordinate to take the built ui files and send them to user?

Comment: What is a "react server"? React is a JS library used to make front end UIs and a server (in this case) is a backend service that host files and provides functionality. They're completely different.

Comment: So a basic example is, you have a simple React app that gets converted to a single Javascript file,  `app.js`, when it's built. Then you have an `index.html` which imports that `app.js` file. Next, you have a Node server which hosts that `index.html` on the root url (which is `/`), let's say on port 9000 as an example. So when your browser navigates to that address (e.g. `localhost:9000`) the Node server returns the index.html and the `app.js` it imports. And then your app is displayed in the browser.

Comment: @Jayce444 I know that! But we run a server to built that files and get served! not? run something like http://localhost/... for react also! Confused

Comment: @Jayce444 Anyway, your second explanation is very good and help me to know the process but i should try read something about my understanding of react that run something like http://l...

Comment: Ok well it sounds like you guys may already use a tool that builds and hosts React stuff for you. In which case that might cause confusion. Maybe try to create a super simple barebones setup, which is very basic React app hosted by a very basic Node server. Might help to clear things up :) if you have another application/tool that automates building/hosting of React stuff (while that may be useful down the line) I think it'll confuse you when you're trying to learn the basics.

Comment: @Jayce444 One clarification, React need a node runtime to build it!? So it could be a node server that serve its building?

Comment: It will use Node tools to build it, but once it's built then anything can serve the built files. Building and serving have no dependency on each other. You can serve with that same Node environment that built it, or you can serve them with a Flask (Python) server, or Java, or whatever you'd like. If you want to serve with a Node Express server then you can, though it's not required.

Comment: @Jayce444 I know that when its built as ui html css ..., it could be served ... . my question is something else, i mean, the tools that built it, is a node server that built it! wow confused too much because i see that both server get running one for reach and one for express and we use proxy in config file of react! i should found the article and then come back to you again